# Vim Jedi Plugin -- Add .sage filetype

Tags: plugin-system, filetype, filetype-python, linux-debian

```
      ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.        OS: Debian 9.9 stretch
    ,g$$P""       """Y$$.".      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.19.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
   ,$$P'              `$$$.      Uptime: 3h 17m
  ',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:    Packages: 2012
  `d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$     Shell: zsh 5.3.1
   $$P      d$'     ,    $$P     Resolution: 1920x1080
   $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'     DE: XFCE
   $$\;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      WM: Xfwm4
   Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'          WM Theme: Moheli
   `$$b      "-.__               GTK Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2]
    `Y$$                         Icon Theme: Zafiro-icons
     `Y$$.                       Font: TeX Gyre Bonum 10
       `$$b.                     CPU: Intel Core i5-6440HQ CPU @ 3.5GHz
         `Y$$b.                  GPU: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) 
            `"Y$b._              RAM: 4804MiB / 7599MiB
                `""""
```

I am using *vim* together with the pluging *python-jedi*. I would like to edit my .sage program with vim to but the filetype .sage is not recognized by the plugin as python's file (where the content is in python).

How can I associate .sage files to the jedi plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `~/.vim/ftdetect/sage.vim` (create if not present):

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sage setfiletype python
```

cf. [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/44.html), which directs to appropriate help pages.